# mypy ignores wrong type in dataclass member

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing, python-dataclasses

This code contains a huge type error, which *mypy* misses:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

class WrongThing:
    def do_wrong_way(self):
        pass

class RightThing:
    def do_right_way(self):
        pass

@dataclass
class Holder:
    thing: RightThing
    def fill_thing(self):
        self.thing.do_wrong_way()  # <--- This is wrong

m = Holder(RightThing())
m.fill_thing()
```

Why doesn't *mypy* object that `self.thing` lacks a `do_wrong_way` attribute? Am I doing something, er, wrong?

*mypy* does correctly flag this code with an `[attr-defined]` error:

```
r = RightThing()
r.do_wrong_way()   # <--- [attr-defined] error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let this be a lesson *never* to leave a function definition unannotated, even if it seems trivial!

Mypy passes this code because MyPy's default setting is to ignore functions that "have no type annotations", as it is assumed that the user wants these to be "dynamic functions" that the user doesn't want type-checked. This is mentioned in the documentation [here](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html#function-signatures-and-dynamic-vs-static-typing).

In your `Holder` class, you have no annotations in the signature of the `fill_thing` method at all, so mypy just doesn't look at it at all. If you change your Holder class to this, so that `fill_thing` is explicitly annotated as returning `None`:

```
@dataclass
class Holder:
    thing: RightThing
    def fill_thing(self) -> None:
        self.thing.do_wrong_way()
```

... Then Mypy [raises an error](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=show-error-codes&gist=fe69c4d5a0419d8bf634f835bc821b5a), just as we'd expect!

---

**How to avoid these errors in the future**

I recommend always running mypy with the `--strict` setting, as with `strict=True`, MyPy [will warn you](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=show-error-codes%2Cstrict&gist=d9e38cf27774fa7d51247c2dd5f23218) if you leave any functions without type annotations. While the default setting of "we won't raise errors if you leave the function unannotated" is probably more beginner-friendly, I personally find it just leads to an unfortunate number of bugs if you don't use Mypy with the `--strict` setting.

Another option, if you'd like unannotated functions to be checked, but don't want MyPy to be *quite* as strict as it is with the `--strict` option, is to run MyPy with [the `--check-untyped-defs` option](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-check-untyped-defs). A full list of command-line options can be found in the documentation [here](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#the-mypy-command-line).

Comment: So _that's_ why I see so many examples of functions annotated `-> None`!

Comment: @BenKovitz yup!